# Round values without increment

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a column which contains this number `22403293365.500000`, and I want to display it like this `22403293365` instead of `22403293366`.

Is it possible in PostgreSQL?

Comment: [floor function](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/floor.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this

```
SELECT FLOOR(22403293365.500000 ) AS "output";
```

Comment: Simply use floor function